# Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, graphql-js

I have a component that's rendering on page load and then making some calls to get data client side. On initial load everything works as expected. However when i click a see more button to make a new call theres an error in the console saying "rendered more hooks than during the previous render". Does anyone have any input on what can be edited here? Because I am a little lost at this point

```
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (react-dom.development.js:15115)
    at updateMemo (react-dom.development.js:15583)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:16055)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1607)
    at SecondCall (SecondCall.js:30)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14938)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17169)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18745)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:182)
```

```js
const SomeItems = (guid) => {
  const {
    data: dataR,
    loading: loadingR,
    error: errorR
  } = useQuery(
    'foo',
    {
      variables: { guid }
    }
  );

  const list = dataR?.foo?.relatedProducts || [];
  const urls = list.map((prod) => prod.url);
  const properties = urls.map((url) => url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
  const firstvalues = properties.slice(0, 3) || [];

  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Shop this Project</h4>
      <div id="values">
        {
          flag
          ? <SecondCall properties={[properties]} />
          : <FirstCall properties={[firstvalues]} />
        }
        <div>
          <button
            id="products"
            type="button"
            onClick={() => setFlag(true)}
          >
            See More
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
export const SecondCall = ( properties ) => {
  const valueArray = Object.values(properties);
  const [[destructedValues]] = valueArray;
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useQuery(
    'foo2',
    {
      variables:{ value: destructedValues}
    }
  );

  if (!data || loading || error) {
    return null;
  }

  const list = data?.foo2?.prods || [];
  const items = list.map((prods) => prods.id);
  const {
    data: dataFLS,
    loading: loadingFLS,
    error: errorFLS,
  } = useQuery(
    'foo3',
    {
      variables: {items}
    }
  );

  if (!dataFLS || loadingFLS || errorFLS) {
    return null;
  }

  const data = dataFLS?.foo3?.prods || [];
  return data.map((products, index) => (
    <div key={`prods-${index}`}>
      <Row key={`related-products-${index}`}>
        "some divs get rendered with data" 
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
export const firstCall = ( firstvalues ) => {
  const valueArray = Object.values(firstvalues);
  const [[destructedValues]] = valueArray;
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error,
  } = useQuery(
    'foo2',
    {
      variables: { value: destructedValues}
    }
  );

  if (!data || loading || error) {
    return null;
  }

  const list = data?.foo2?.prods || [];
  const items = list.map((prods) => prods.id);
  const {
    data: dataFLS,
    loading: loadingFLS,
    error: errorFLS,
  } = useQuery(
    'foo3',
    {
      variables: {items}
    }
  );

  if (!dataFLS || loadingFLS || errorFLS) {
    return null;
  }

  const data = dataFLS?.foo3?.prods || [];
  return data.map((products, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={`prods-${index}`}>
        <Row key={`related-products-${index}`}>
          "some divs get rendered with data" 
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you using react-query? If so, please add it as a tag.

Comment: graphql queries

Comment: I (somewhat) cleaned up your formatting for you. Sometimes you use extra whitespace around delimiters like braces and parens and sometimes you don't, your use of whitespace to denote blocks was completely off, sometimes you used semicolons and in other places you didn't. **That kind of shotgun formatting makes it *extremely easy* for *trivial* errors to escape your notice.** Like misspelling firstCall as 'firsCall', which I also fixed for you. In the future **please correct these sorts of things *before* posting a question.** Thank you.

Comment: In this case, your problem is that early return `if (!data || loading || error) {
    return null;
  }` if it triggers the second call to `useQuery` never happens which violates the rules of hooks.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for the formatting errors. But this helped out a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SecondCall component, you return null in an if statement. But since useQuery is a hook, all useQuery statements need to be run **before** you return anything.

```
const {data, loading, error} = useQuery('foo2', {
  variables:{ value: destructedValues}
})

const list = data?.foo2?.prods || [];
const items = list.map((prods) => prods.id);

const {data: dataFLS, loading: loadingFLS, error: errorFLS} = useQuery('foo3', {
  variables: {items}
});

if (!data || loading || error || !dataFLS || loadingFLS || errorFLS) {
    return null;
}
```

Edit: Apparently you use two useQuery statements in FirsCall too. The same logic applies there.